# Set php session value to text box value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am working on a PHP "interactive text game" for an assignment.

In my program, the user is prompted to enter information (character name, etc) into various text boxes that appear one after another as the user completes the previous text field.

What I want to do is obtain the value of the text box (the user input) and store it in a PHP session.  I understand that I will want to use AJAX in order to get the text value dynamically.

I don't want to have to click a "submit" button first, I want to store the value as soon as the user presses enter or clicks out of the box.

Here is a sampling of the code I have so far, not including unnecessary lines like including ajax/stylesheets/etc.

This portion of the code, namely the `$('input').keypress` method, should get the text from the text field with `"#name"` and... give it to some PHP code somewhere?  I'm extremely new to PHP and Javascript :(

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input').focus(function() {
                    $(this).val("");
                    $('input').keypress(function(event)
                    //.focusout(function()
                     {
                        if (event.which === 13) {
                            $(this).parent().next('div.sub-container').show();
                            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                                }
                            }
                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "globals.php?q=" + $(this).val(), true);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                        }
                    });
                    $('input').focusout(function() {
                        $(this).parent().next('div.sub-container').show();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="" method="get">
                <div class="sub-container-init">
                    <p class = "text">Like all good stories, we need a compelling hero.  Someone with a nice-sounding name.  Have anything good?</p>
                    <input id="name" name="name" value="Name" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is in the separate page `globals.php`.  Ideally, the following PHP will take that text obtained from the text field and store in in a session that I can access from the other page.

```
<?php
$q=$_REQUEST["q"]; 
echo $q;
?>
```

Summary:  How can I store the text value from `"#name"` in a PHP session that I can access later on in the same page?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` needs to be inside all files using sessions. You didn't mention/show it in your 2nd body of code.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you!  I'll add that.  I assume they will refer to the same session and have access to the same variables?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if using the same session's name inside both files.

Answer (score 0):

Use **session_start();** at the beginning page you will need to use  $_SESSION['name'];
note that you can't have anything echoed before session_start or you will get an error